# Squid Proxy has thousands 'cache_peer'

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy, squid

I tried having 1000 lines of cache_peer and its working correctly, however when i added ten of thousands of cache_peer, and i cant really connect to it. Any idea why ?

My goal is to have hundred or thousands of authenticated users connect to my ProxyServer and my ProxyServer would then forward to another proxy provider (oxylab, smartproxy, etc). Not sure if Squid is the correct choice for this case!

The squid proxy does not work when I add 20,000 'cache_peer'.

How to fix?

My Server:

- Ubuntu: 18.04
- 16GB Ram and 8CPU
- 500GB SSD

Please help!